# DIY power bank with NiMH batteries

Tags: batteries, nimh, powerbanks

I want to do a DIY power bank with NiMH batteries, like [this example](https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Power-Bank-2/)... But I have 6 NiMH batteries with 2600 mAh and 1.2 V.

I want to use a [18650 PCB LCD](https://es.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-usb-5v-mobile-power-bank-18650-battery-charger-pcb-module-board.html) but [they are designed for Li-ion 18650](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32694942781.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.ef917cf3ST7h6z&algo_pvid=1a7bfae9-840c-419c-b21c-f77a59d2045f&algo_exp_id=1a7bfae9-840c-419c-b21c-f77a59d2045f-5) batteries, not NiMH batteries.

- Is it safe to use this type of PCB with NiMH batteries?
- If it's safe... what is the best organization/circuit to connect 6 batteries with 2600 mAh and 1.2 V?
- If it's not safe... what circuit can I use for this purpose?

Comment: Charging and discharging of NiMH cells is very different from charging and discharging of Lithium cells. Why are you worried about safety if they are not even compatible?

Comment: @Justme because I am a newbie in electronics and I don't have much idea, that's why I ask

Comment: Maybe there's a dedicated all in one power bank module for nimh but it would be pretty niche. Usb power banks have pretty much always been lithium based. You could use individual parts, like a nimh charger module and a 5v step up or down regulator module.